# PayPal: "Item Category value is invalid. Only Digital or Physical are allowed" - on CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here is my request:

```
Array ( [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile [VERSION] => 69.0 [PWD] => 1314109393 [USER] => redhot_1314109355_biz_api1.gmail.com [SIGNATURE] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AvgAV2SBYw.2L13vmrlieTUPAScT [TOKEN] => EC-8AD12321RD892010L [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2011-10-10T03:00:00 [DESC] => Description: [BILLINGPERIOD] => SemiMonth [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1 [AMT] => 35 [CURRENCYCODE] => USD [EMAIL] => redhotberry@gmail.com [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0] => Digital [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => BearPlan [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 35 [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1 )
```

And here is response:

```
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2011-09-06T09:51:40Z [CORRELATIONID] => 8eb81baa4e80e [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 69.0 [BUILD] => 2085867 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 13701 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Data [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Item Category value is invalid. Only Digital or Physical are allowed. [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error ) )
```

Comment: I'd suggest logging a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Services at https://www.paypal.com/mts/ -- they can look into it from their end and find detailed information on why it's returning this eventhough you specified the correct category.

Comment: VitalyP, please update this problem if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add another field for 'L_ITEMCATEGORY0', some PayPal calls require this.